# using location.reload in edge doesn't work

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to refresh my page after using some event 
using this javascript method 
`setTimeout(location.reload.bind(location), 2000);`

it's work as well in Chrome 
but when I tried it in Edge it gives error

```
SCRIPT65535: Invalid calling object
```

Comment: setTimeout(() => localtion.reload(location), 2000) it seems that edge has problem with bind use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 2000);
```

Comment: it's work idk why Edge has a problem with bind() function

Answer (score 1):

Syntax like this

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

Comment: there's nothing wrong in syntax 
it's MS edge  JS has a problem with bind method